# Create an object if it is not already in the set

Tags: c++

Having a set of pointers to unique objects of type `A`, I want to *create* and *insert* a new element in the set, but only if there is no such element already.
The problem is, the standard comparators operate existing objects, and one is not yet exist. That means that I can not determine if an object is in the set without creating the object (or without iterating the whole set manually).

One obvious solution would be to replace the set by a map with keys containing a part of `A` that makes objects of type `A` unique, but it almost doubles memory usage. It is unacceptable to me.

Any ideas?

UPDATE
To be more concrete, here is a simplified example:

```
class Base { /* members */ };

class Derived : public Base {
  static std::set<Derived *> cache;
  std::vector<Object *> v;
 public:
  static Derived *Create(const std::vector<Object *> &v);
  /* other members */
};

Derived *Derived::Create(const std::vector<Object *> &v) {
  /* Here I need to create and insert a new object of type Derived
     into the `Derived::cache`, but only if there is no such object
     in the set yet. Objects are uniqued by contents of `v`. */
}
```

Comment: Look at [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to search for an existing object.  If not found, then create+insert the new object.

Comment: `the standard comparators operate existing objects, and one is not yet exist.` Sorry I don't get it at all. Why you can't implement `operator<` again?

Comment: Like @BryanChen has said - just define your own compare operator.

Comment: @Remy - doesn't that require iterating over the set which the OP apparently doesn't want to do?

Comment: Presumably they already have a custom compare operator.  Otherwise every _new_ object added to a set of pointers would be unique.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, I missed it. But as latedeveloper noted, it has O(N) complexity in the worst case.

Comment: @СергейБаранников - I don't know what your insert requirements are and how often you would be inserting vs. how often you would be searching, but could you use a `std::vector` as your container (less memory requirement than a set) and maintain it in a sorted order. Then you can use a binary search to check for the existing item and then do the create and insert if needed. (Granted that you may need to implement your own binary search per your requirement that you do not have an object to "compare" with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find_if` taking an arbitrary type is supported in c++14:

```
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

//
// the concept of an Identity - some signature that identifies an object
// uniquely
struct Identity
{
  Identity(int v) : v_(v) {}

  auto as_tuple() const { return std::tie(v_); }

  private:
  int v_;
};
bool operator<(Identity const& l, Identity const& r)
{
  return l.as_tuple() < r.as_tuple();
}

//
// some object that has an identity
//
struct Thing
{
  Thing(Identity i) : ident_(std::move(i)) {}

  const Identity& identity() const { return ident_; }

private:
  Identity ident_;
};

struct LessThing
{
  struct is_transparent {};

  bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<const Thing>& l, const Identity& r) const
  {
    return l->identity() < r;
  }

  bool operator()(const Identity& l, const std::unique_ptr<const Thing>& r) const
  {
    return l < r->identity();
  }

  bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<const Thing>& l, const std::unique_ptr<const Thing>& r) const
  {
    return l->identity() < r->identity();
  }

};


int main()
{
  std::set<std::unique_ptr<const Thing>, LessThing> myset;
  myset.insert(std::make_unique<Thing>(Identity(5)));
  myset.insert(std::make_unique<Thing>(Identity(6)));

  if (myset.find(Identity(7)) == myset.end())
  {
      myset.emplace(std::make_unique<Thing>(Identity(7)));
  }  
}
```

Note1: the definition of the type `is_transparent` in the comparison functor to enable this behaviour.

Note2: Remember that the elements of a set are constants. If the key comparison depends on an object that is being pointed to by the pointer in the set, that data (or at least the identifying part of it) must be immutable.

Comment: Perfect, except one minor thing: identifying part of the object has to be moved to the identity member (to avoid undesired excessive memory usage). Need to meditate on this.

Comment: that's straightforward - I have created two Identifier objects in this case, but you could compare against one and then move it in.

Comment: I meant that identifying members of the original object (`v` of class `Derived` in my case) have to be transfered (not to be confused with std::move) into the newly introduced identifying member (`ident_` in your code). But I believe there is a way of not doing it, by constructing `Identity` on the fly in `identity` member function. That is why I need to meditate.

Comment: @SergeyBarannikov if ident consists of component parts you can write an operator() overload that compares a pointer to Thing with a `std::tuple` of const references to component parts. Then you could `mymap.find(std::tie(partA, partB, partC))` etc. However at this point, building the identifier may not be as expensive as you think, after optimisations.

Comment: Yes, ident consists of components of the class. I thought about something like changing `Thing` to `struct Thing { int key; const Identity& identity() const { return Identity(key); }` and not changing operator()s, what is similar to your last proposal, but without using std::tuple and std::tie. Building the indentifier is not a problem. The problems are: a) having a duplicate of a part of the original class in the ident (excessive memory usage) or b) inconcistent access to members of  the class if some members have been moved into the `ident` member.

Comment: @SergeyBarannikov If you put enough overloads on the comparison function you can of course compare anything you want to anything else. In your shoes I might be inclined to write it simply once, and then optimise later if necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130446/discussion-between-sergey-barannikov-and-richard-hodges).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call set::count.

count will then call the '<' operator on the object you pass it, plus the objects in the set. So you must construct an object.

But the '<' operator does not need to access every field. Probably. If you absolutely must compare on every field then there is no solution other than to create the query object. But most likely the object has an Id or similar field you use for fast comparison.
So you need a special constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
  int id;
  std::vector<int> expensive_member;
  friend bool operator < (MyClass const &, MyClass const &);

  public:
  MyClass(std::vector<int> const &expensivetosetup, int id);
  MyClass(int id);
  void member() { assert(expensive_member.empty() == false);} 
}

bool operator < (MyClass const &a, MyClass const &b)
{
   return a.id < b.id;
}
```

Set it up like that. Then the special constructor is only used to create
a cheap query object. For a bit of extra safety, we wrap assert fails
round the other members so the partially constructed objects can't be
used for anything else.

It should be stressed that this is poor design. The real answer is to use
a key / value pair and take the key out of the object if memory
requires that. But sometimes other pressures create bad designs, and this is your answer.

Comment: I can't move the key out of the object, because the data that happened to be the key is a semantic part of the object. On the other hand, since this data do uniquely identify the object, it is natural to use it as a key when an object of this type is stored in a container like `std::set`. Looks like the WG21 committee had this in mind when they invented C++14. Thanks and take a look at the accepted answer for details.